# Jquery- Handling promise object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, promise

```
var xyz = chart.exporting.getImage("png").then(function (imgdata) {

});
```

The above function **xyz** is a promising object **how to get whether the object is full filled  or not 
based on the promiseStatus,refer the picture .**

After full filled i want to execute the below code

```
   var image = imgdata.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');


                    jQuery.ajax({

                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: "VATReportGeneration.aspx/SetImageInSession",
                                data: JSON.stringify({ "image": image }),
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {

                                    if (data != '') {
                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            cache: false,
                                            url: file,
                                            success: function (data) {

                                                url = '';
                                                url = "../../ReportHandler/VATConfigurationFileHandler.aspx";
                                                file = '';
                                                file = url + "?ReportByte=1";
                                                $get("exporthandler").src = file;
                                                chart.dispose();
                                                document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
                                                //document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
                                            },
                                            error: function (data) {

                                                //document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }

                    });
```

Console **[image: executed when the promising object is full filled]**. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to promisify the ajax method?

Comment: @Supercool. XYZ promising object is a referred from the plugin. The imgdata returns the base64 string once this completed I need to pass that image to the 'VATReportGeneration.aspx/SetImageInSession'  and those script should be executed synchronously.

Comment: whats this plugin?

Comment: @lndgalante I can't understand but let me explain that the imgdata returns base64 string and the I want to pass that imgdata as a parameter to the ajax call 'VATReportGeneration.aspx/SetImageInSession'  but before returning full base64 string it passes the partial base64 string to the ajax call. Please help me bro. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got answer from my colleague by passing a chart object to a callback function from call back function I have converted the chart to 64basestring.

Answer (score 0):

Write your image data `imgdata` handling logic code inside `.then`

More here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/#Triggering_export

```
  chart.exporting.getImage("png").then(function (imgdata) {
     var image = imgdata.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
     //your ajax call and other logic here
     ......
     .......
   }
```

Comment: I have wrote the logic which you have specified but imgdata returns only partial data. For eg:256kb of data it only returns 36kb of data. I can get full data while placing all snippet code inside the setTimeout function with 3000ms but    it some time takes 5000ms or 8000ms it depends on the data. When i set 3000ms some times it returns partial data.

Comment: your original question was to handle the promise

Comment: Yes once promising is full fiilled then I would like to use ajax call